# minSDKversion 15 cannot run on android device version : 4.3

Tags: java, android

Sorry for yesterday not well  defined question about this.

```
Here is my build.gradle code:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.me.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       multiDexEnabled true

       }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


    repositories {

    mavenCentral ()
 }


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',     {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
```

i read that the minSDKVersion is :

```
min sdk version Is the earliest release of the Android SDK that your application can run on. Usually this is because of a problem with the earlier APIs, lacking functionality, or some other behavioral issue.

target sdk version The version your application was targeted to run on. Ideally this is because of some sort of optimal run conditions. If you were to "make your app for version 19" this is where that would be specified. It may run on earlier or later releases, but this is what you were aiming for. This is mostly to indicate how current your application is for use in the marketplace, etc.

compile sdk version The version of android your IDE (or other means of compiling I suppose) uses to make your app when you publish a .apk file. This is useful for testing your application as it is a common need to compile your app as you develop it. As this will be the version to compile to an APK, it will naturally be the version of your release. Likewise it is advisable to have this match you target sdk version.
```

i tested on device that has Android Version 7.1 API (25) and it works but when i test it on phone that is Android Version 4.3 (API 18) it gives  me "Unfortunately,App has stopped". 
Really hope that i defined this time the question.
Thanks

Comment: Android Monitor logs?

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your activities, maybe you have targeted a higher version in an activity. Check for any @TargetApi(--) in your code and change code which corresponds to it